# ArcGIS Online Identify operation on webmap via REST

Tags: arcgis-online, identify

Is it possible to perform an Identify operation on an ArcGIS Online webmap via the REST API (not via the javascipt api), equivalent to identifying on an ArcGIS Server map service? With Server, we use something like:

http://arcgisserverurl/MapServer/identify?identifyparametersgohere

So we're looking for something like:

http://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/webmapid/identify?identifyparametersgohere

Big picture: We have quite a bit of code set up to access street centerline data from the identify operation on an ArcGIS Server map service.  We're now finding clients who have their data on ArcGIS Online, and are trying to figure out a way to use our current code to access the data.

If it's not possible to identify on a web map, what options are available to query ArcGIS Online data via a REST API?

Comment: Probably yes, with a query - but what information is it that you want exactly, and in what format? Also please provide an example of what an identify is. Is that an XY point, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

See the following URL, it sends parameters to the QUERY REST end point of a MapService. It spits out a lot of information in JSON. (make sure to include the **=*** at the end of the below URL, the parser here doesn't like it)

http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/DamageAssessment/MapServer/0/query?where=&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=-9793636.8862%2C5099812.731799997&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&returnGeometry=true&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&f=pjson&outFields=*

To break it down, if you've set

- geometry=X,Y
- geometryType=esriGeometryPoint
- outputFields=*  (or = certain fields, comma separated)
- f=json (or pjson)

It'll act like an identify operation from a click. But you need to know the XY to pass in.

To get a complete list of values you can pass in, just check the query end point or read more in the API doc: http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/DamageAssessment/MapServer/0/query